# How to cluster data based on thirty minutes interval timestamps from a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have a dataframe containing varied timestamps for a metric named epi. The sample is as follows

```
             epi    timestamp
30000   8.943856    2019-02-13 00:51:24.238+00
30001   8.220877    2019-02-13 00:51:25.238+00
30002   8.220877    2019-02-13 00:51:26.238+00
30003   5.885678    2019-02-13 00:51:27.238+00
30004   5.506963    2019-02-13 00:51:28.238+00
30005   5.436130    2019-02-13 00:51:29.238+00
30006   5.109536    2019-02-13 00:51:30.237+00
30007   4.302602    2019-02-13 00:51:31.238+00
30008   2.910839    2019-02-13 00:51:32.238+00
30009   3.596520    2019-02-13 00:51:33.237+00
30010   5.167294    2019-02-13 00:51:34.238+00
30011   5.037999    2019-02-13 00:51:35.238+00
30012   4.848845    2019-02-13 00:51:36.238+00
30013   4.953263    2019-02-13 00:51:37.238+00
30014   5.421831    2019-02-13 00:51:38.238+00
70832   1.962402    2019-02-12 18:50:52.375+00
70833   1.910290    2019-02-12 18:50:53.376+00
70834   2.009980    2019-02-12 18:50:54.374+00
70835   2.009980    2019-02-12 18:50:55.376+00
70836   2.064527    2019-02-12 18:50:56.357+00
70837   2.030039    2019-02-12 18:50:57.372+00
70838   2.030039    2019-02-12 18:50:58.374+00
70839   2.082839    2019-02-12 18:50:59.376+00
```

I want to build individual dataframes according to intervals like `18:00-18:30`, `18:30-7:00`, and so on from this dataframe. The dataframes are to be formed according to days and 30 minute intervals. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is `df.groupby(pd.Grouper)` close to what you're looking for? For example:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq='30min')).sum()

                                 epi
timestamp                           
2019-02-12 18:30:00+00:00  16.100096
2019-02-12 19:00:00+00:00   0.000000
2019-02-12 19:30:00+00:00   0.000000
2019-02-12 20:00:00+00:00   0.000000
2019-02-12 20:30:00+00:00   0.000000
2019-02-12 21:00:00+00:00   0.000000
2019-02-12 21:30:00+00:00   0.000000
2019-02-12 22:00:00+00:00   0.000000
2019-02-12 22:30:00+00:00   0.000000
2019-02-12 23:00:00+00:00   0.000000
2019-02-12 23:30:00+00:00   0.000000
2019-02-13 00:00:00+00:00   0.000000
2019-02-13 00:30:00+00:00  83.563110
```